# Error When Creating a View or Controller in Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I get the following error when I attempt to add a View or Controller to my monodevelop project: `Invalid SDK Version Name`

I am using Monodevelop 4.0, which I got from the following PPA: `Launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest`

And I installed mono using `sudo-apt get install mono-complete`

mono -V in terminal tells me that the version is 2.10.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. Apparently, Monodevelop 4.0 is not stabe and 3.1 should be used for mvc development

Answer (score 0):

Monodevelop can use another runtime than default. Check your **Project > Active Runtime** setting and try to choose another option than already selected.